# How can i use regular expressions in R to extract peoples names

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract a name field from a text eg

```
name = "My name is John Smith"
```

should return *John Smith*

My current code is

```
grep(".^[A-Z][a-z]+\\s[A-Z][a-z]+", name, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you give more sample input data?

Comment: related: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Remove `.^` from your pattern and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` to capture the words that start with uppercase, followed by lower case, then a space followed by the word with upper case, lower case letters of the string followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*([A-Z][a-z]+\\s[A-Z][a-z]+).*", "\\1", name)
#[1] "John Smith"
```

edit: added @DJack's recommendation

#### data

```
name <- c("My name is John Smith")
```

Comment: To cover more cases, in particular when the name is in the middle of the text, you may want to replace `$` by `.*`